# Consuming JSON API using PHP

Tags: php, json, api, file-get-contents, jsondecoder

I have read and tried some code that I found in other posts with similar issues but I couldn't find a solution.

I'm using this API: https://api.ipma.pt/open-data/forecast/meteorology/cities/daily/1100900.json which returns this:

```
  {
      "owner": "IPMA",
      "country": "PT",
      "data": [
        {
          "precipitaProb": "0.0",
          "tMin": "12.6",
          "tMax": "24.0",
          "predWindDir": "N",
          "idWeatherType": 3,
          "classWindSpeed": 2,
          "longitude": "-8.8069",
          "forecastDate": "2020-05-22",
          "latitude": "39.7473"
        },
        {
          "precipitaProb": "0.0",
          "tMin": "13.1",
          "tMax": "24.2",
          "predWindDir": "N",
          "idWeatherType": 5,
          "classWindSpeed": 2,
          "longitude": "-8.8069",
          "forecastDate": "2020-05-23",
          "latitude": "39.7473"
        },
        {
          "precipitaProb": "0.0",
          "tMin": "12.8",
          "tMax": "26.5",
          "predWindDir": "NW",
          "idWeatherType": 2,
          "classWindSpeed": 1,
          "longitude": "-8.8069",
          "forecastDate": "2020-05-24",
          "latitude": "39.7473"
        },
        {
          "precipitaProb": "0.0",
          "tMin": "13.4",
          "tMax": "26.0",
          "predWindDir": "NW",
          "idWeatherType": 5,
          "classWindSpeed": 1,
          "longitude": "-8.8069",
          "forecastDate": "2020-05-25",
          "latitude": "39.7473"
        },
        {
          "precipitaProb": "3.0",
          "tMin": "16.3",
          "tMax": "31.7",
          "predWindDir": "E",
          "idWeatherType": 2,
          "classWindSpeed": 2,
          "longitude": "-8.8069",
          "forecastDate": "2020-05-26",
          "latitude": "39.7473"
        }
      ],
      "globalIdLocal": 1100900,
      "dataUpdate": "2020-05-22T14:31:04"
    }
```

I need to get several values from the "**data**" array.

So far i have this:

```
<?php

$api_url = file_get_contents('https://api.ipma.pt/open-data/forecast/meteorology/cities/daily/1100900.json');
$forecastLeiria = json_decode($api_url);

var_dump($forecastLeiria);

?>
```

Returns **NULL** even tho the API is working just fine.

Cheers!

Comment: Odd. The same code seems to work on my end. Try just dumping the $api_url and see what that gets you.

Comment: Is [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) on?

Comment: var_dump($api_url) returns bool(false)... might be the problem.

Comment: There is no other logical explanation for the behavior; as the URL exists and the JSON is valid.

Comment: Well, i have no idea how to solve this. I'll try to use **cURL** instead of **file_get_contents**...

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it works fine on my end.
A possible cause of this problem might be your PHP configuration.
Please run `phpinfo()` , scroll to the Core section and check that that the **allow_url_fopen** directive is turned on. If it is off, then you need to turn it on in your **php.ini** configuration file.
It is the directive that allows PHP scripts to open public files on the internet and therefore affects how `file_get_contents` function works with public files.

Comment: Thanks. I just did, and **allow_url_fopen** is **ON**. Still not working tho.
[link](https://imgur.com/QDzAf1q)